# Constrained Delaunay triangulation algorithm?

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry, discrete-mathematics, triangulation

I am trying to find a resource which explains how to compute the constrained Delaunay triangulation of a set of points and edge constraints, I found [these slides](https://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/discgeom/dates/2nd_ERC_Workshop/slides/inc3-talk.pdf) by Jonathan Shewchuck, but without the presenter it's hard to follow.

Ideally I am looking for a strategy that only involves edge flipping, without the need for deletion and reinsertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Johnathan Shewchuck's UC Berkely website [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejrs/), which contains:

- Excellent [lecture notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejrs/meshpapers/delnotes.pdf) on Delaunay Mesh Generation
- [sample chapters](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejrs/meshbook.html) from the book "Delaunay Mesh Generation" (which might well be worth buying)
- Many other excellent papers and references

Ages ago, I have used his lecture notes to implement Constrained Delaunay Triangulations in Scala. If You're interested, you can find the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/DirkToewe/DelTri4S).

I am not sure what you mean by flipping instead of deletion. Technically, edge flipping is the removal of two triangles followed by an insertion of two other triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Page 7 of "[FAST ALGORITHM FOR GENERATING CONSTRAINED DELAUNAY TRIANGULATIONS](https://www.newcastle.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0019/22519/23_A-fast-algortithm-for-generating-constrained-Delaunay-triangulations.pdf)" (a publication on a CDT algorithm) explains the process very clearly and the figures are extremely useful.